# "Transaction has been rejected by the EVM:" - why does the error occur?

Tags: next.js, solidity, smartcontracts, metamask

## The essence of the problem

A window opens in Meta mask about paying for gas. I can click continue, but I can't wait for the positive completion of the transaction once - an error always

occurs{"blockHash":"0x33e1cd0a7c540d9cb08319bfdeae2ab87bf7a81f1daec361298f9735260c4b93",
"blockNumber":"9968588",
"cumulativeGasUsed":"1339077",
"effectiveGasPrice":"2500000010",
"from":"0x****************",
"gasUsed":"21069",
"logs"[],
"logsBloom":"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",

"status":"0",
"to":"0x4f37382283719cf4151e27412c60472303fd158f",
"transactionHash":"0x375c55a6e8f29eddd454e3a7bbf0af4245d3c44cfccea87bade47441c1941857",
"transactionIndex":"1","type":"2"}"

---

I'm trying using *Next.js* write an interface for a smart contract, which is shown below:

```
contract CampaignFactory {
    address payable[] public deployedCampaigns;

    function createCampaign(uint minimum) public {
        address newCampaign = address(new Campaign(minimum, msg.sender));
        deployedCampaigns.push(payable(newCampaign));
    }

    function CreateNewIdenticalCampaign() public {
        address newCampaign = address(new Campaign(100, msg.sender));
        deployedCampaigns.push(payable(newCampaign));
    }

    function getDeployedCampaigns()
        public
        view
        returns (address payable[] memory)
    {
        return deployedCampaigns;
    }
}
```

---

The **get (getDeployedCampaigns)** method works very well in the Remix Ethereum IDE and in my application.

But there are troubles with post methods. I can immediately say with confidence that the **post** methods are not broken, since everything in them works perfectly, but only in the Remix. I assume that the code in my application is written incorrectly in the ***.js* file:

```
const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
      const minimumWei = web3.utils.toWei(
        this.state.minimumContribution,
        "ether"
      );

      const gas = await factory.methods
        .createCampaign(minimumWei)
        .estimateGas({ from: accounts[0] });

      await factory.methods
        .createCampaign(minimumWei)
        .send({
          from: accounts[0],
          gas: 10000000, //web3.utils.toHex(gas),
          gasPrice: web3.utils.toWei("0.0001", "gwei"),
        })
        .on("transactionHash", function (hash) {
          console.log("Transaction send, hash: " + hash);
        })
        .on("receipt", function (receipt) {
          console.log("Done, : " + receipt.blockNumber);
        })
        .on("error", function (error) {
          console.error("Error: " + error.message);
        });
```

I tried not to specify the gas, gas Price properties, but nothing helps.

Answer (score 0):

So good! I found the answer to the question, it turns out that in 2023 you need to program differently than in 2019 in web3 - you also need to send the method ABI, here is a working version of the code:

```
const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
      const encode = await factory.methods.createCampaign(100).encodeABI();
      await factory.methods
        //.CreateNewIdenticalCampaign()
        .createCampaign(this.state.minimumContribution)
        .send({
          from: accounts[0],
          data: encode
        });
```

Comment: Got a citation of where you found it for the record?

Comment: A ready-made solution could not be found anywhere, I guessed thanks to the documentation to add an ABI to the request. Here is a link to the documentation: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html